# Terraform EKS EFS Recreated On Each Apply

Tags: terraform, amazon-eks, amazon-efs

I've Terraformed an AWS EKS cluster and EFS filesystem.

Everytime Terraform is applied, the EFS is replaced. This should not be happening.

Versions:

- Terraform: v1.1.7
- EKS v1.20

The resources are:

```
resource "aws_efs_file_system" "efs_fs" {
  creation_token = var.eks_efs_name
  encrypted        = "true"
  kms_key_id       = data.aws_kms_alias.efs.arn
  performance_mode = "generalPurpose"
  throughput_mode  = "bursting"
  tags = merge(var.aws_tags, {
    Name = "${var.eks_efs_name}"
  })
}

resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "efs_mt" {
  for_each        = toset(var.eks_wrk_subnets)
  file_system_id  = aws_efs_file_system.efs_fs.id
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.eks_efs.id]
  subnet_id       = each.value
}

resource "aws_efs_access_point" "efs_ap" {
  file_system_id = aws_efs_file_system.efs_fs.id
  tags = merge(var.aws_tags, {
    Name = "${var.eks_efs_name}"
  })
}


resource "aws_security_group" "eks_efs" {
  name   = "${var.eks_efs_name}-sg"
  vpc_id = var.vpc_id

  ingress {
    from_port   = 2049
    to_port     = 2049
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = [var.vpc_cidr_block]
  }

  egress {
    from_port        = 0
    to_port          = 0
    protocol         = "-1"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
  }
}
```

Is there a lifecycle hook missing?

Any pointers or ideas would be much appreciated :-)

## Plan output

There's too much sensitive info to present here, but most EFS resources are being recreated, EFS, Mounts, Access Point and an SG Rule . But what I did noticed is when kms_key_id uses a variable with the KMS key ARN, rather than a datasource, the issue stops. Why is this?

```
resource "aws_efs_file_system" "efs_fs" {
  creation_token = var.eks_efs_name
  encrypted        = "true"
//  kms_key_id       = data.aws_kms_alias.efs.arn
  kms_key_id       = "arn:aws:kms:eu-west-2:012345678901:key/d7812345c-b388-421a-bf1b-0b11212345c"
  performance_mode = "generalPurpose"
  throughput_mode  = "bursting"
  tags = merge(var.aws_tags, {
    Name = "${var.eks_efs_name}"
  })
}
```

## var.eks_efs_name

This value is not changing.

## Datasource with depends_on triggers recreate

I came across [this](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/security-group-rule-resource-is-getting-recreated-with-each-tf-apply/31486/6) article whereby similar issues were seen, when using a datasource lookup inside a security group resource, the resource was recreated on each apply. The fix was to remove depends_on. Is this a known bug?

Comment: Can you show the plan output that wants to replace the resource unexpectedly?

Comment: The value of `var.eks_efs_name` isn't changing?